# Comparing call_user_func vs call_user_func_array vs call_user_method vs call_user_method_array

Tags: php

```
function HelloFunc($Arg1 , $Arg2 , $Arg3 ){
    echo "Arg1 : " . $Arg1 . "\n";
    echo "Arg2 : " . $Arg2 . "\n";
    echo "Arg3 : " . $Arg3 . "\n";
    return "done";
}
```

Comparing Outputs

```
echo call_user_func("HelloFunc" , "1" , "2" , "3");


Arg1 : 1
Arg2 : 2
Arg3 : 3
done

echo call_user_func_array("HelloFunc" , "1" , "2" , "3"); 

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects exactly 2 parameters
```

My question is, the best cases to use **call_user_func & call_user_func_array**

I know **call_user_method & call_user_method_array** are depreciated and does not work in PHP7. And **call_user_func & call_user_func_array** do not work in older PHP.

Is that a good idea to relate following to make it compatible with most php version

```
call_user_method = call_user_func 
call_user_method_array = call_user_func_array
```

Like :

```
function_exists('call_user_method ') ? call_user_method() : call_user_func ();

function_exists('call_user_method_array ') ? call_user_method_array () : call_user_func_array();
```

Comment: for `call_user_func_array`, As the name states that it should an array. So use `call_user_func_array('funntion', $arr)`, For your question `echo call_user_func_array("HelloFunc" , array("1" , "2" , "3")); `

Comment: @FrayneKonok That's fine. But how does that make difference as same array could be passed to call_user_func along with call_user_func_array. Is that just that call_user_func_array accepts two arguments, & call_user_func accepts many

Comment: Yes, you are right this time.

Comment: @FrayneKonok which is right to use in terms of efficiency. Why is there extra function call_user_func_array when things could just happen with call_user_func . I think there should be some difference in usage

Answer (score 3):

> You can use both `call_user_func_array` and `call_user_func`, but
>   depending on your data.

For call_user_func_array, As the name states that it should an array. So use `call_user_func_array('funntion', $arr)`.

For your question `echo call_user_func_array("HelloFunc" , array("1" , "2" , "3"));`.

How is your `HelloFunc` function for this:

```
function HelloFunc($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){

}
```

More details: [function.call-user-func-array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), [function.call-user-func.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: Got this -> Warning: Missing argument 2 for HelloFunc()

Comment: You need to make your function and also parameter like as you pass from this.

Comment: $arr = array("1" , "2" , "3"); call_user_func_array('funntion', $arr)  & call_user_func('funntion', $arr); Do they make any difference ?

Comment: `call_user_func("function_name", 'any_parameter_you_can_pass');` but `call_user_function_array('function_name', 'only_array')`

Comment: So you mean,  call_user_function_array won't accept argument as object or single var(only array) but call_user_func can take any

Comment: `mixed call_user_func ( callable $callback [, mixed $parameter [, mixed $... ]] )`, see the `mixed` in front of parameter.

Comment: Got confused with mixed thing :p

Comment: **Note** The parameters for `call_user_func()` are not passed by reference.

Comment: echo call_user_func_array("HelloFunc" , array("1" , "2" , "3")); This works with HelloFunc($Arg1 , $Arg2 , $Arg3 ). I forgot to save after changing call_user_func to call_user_func_array. And now I do understand the difference. Please correct your answer and also possibly if you could answer 2nd part of my question

Comment: `2nd part of my question`??  What is the question there?

Comment: call_user_method vs call_user_method_array and compatibility

Comment: Those are `DEPRECATED` and `REMOVED`, just through them aside.

Comment: actually need to make my code compatible with old versions of php as well. Is that a good idea to use function_exist method or should I code complete different for older versions